# cy.url().should() failing with type error

Tags: cypress

We have the following piece of code that fails intermittently.

```
cy.url().then((url) => {
   if (url.includes('https://app') || url.includes('https://auth')) {
   cy.url().should('match', /\/agent|\/worker/, { timeout: 30000 })                  ^
  
 }
})
```

The failure happens in the second cy.url() command where the should match condition fails with the error "[object Object]: expected undefined to match". We only see this error every once or so in 10 time.

Comment: You already have the value of the URL in the function as you passed it in - can you just not use that value again? I'm not sure why you are using cy.url() for a second time? Not sure if that is the reason for the failure but I found it confusing.

Comment: That is because the APP does redirect and the URL changes at that stage

Answer (score 1):

Instead of again using `cy.url()`, use the previous url you extracted with `cy.wrap()`, something like this:

```js
cy.url().then((url) => {
  if (url.includes('https://app') || url.includes('https://auth')) {
    cy.wrap(url).should('match', /\/agent|\/worker/, {timeout: 30000})
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the reason for covering multiple scenarios like this would be.

Also, you don't give an example of the url, I'm going to assume your regex is to check the pathname of the url.

```js
cy.location('pathname').should('match', /\/agent|\/worker/i)
```